# How to step thru Perl CGI script when doing POST request

Tags: perl, cgi

to step thru a Perl CGI script with a GET request, for example: http://MyScript.cgi?param1=value1&param2=value2 , we can simply run this command on the shell: perl -d MyScript.cgi param1=value1 param2=value2. But in the case of a POST request that sends those 2 params inside the POST data body ( like an XML data string: <xml><param1 val=value1/><param2 val=value2/></xml> ) instead of as queryStrings on the URL, what would be the command to step thru the MyScript.cgi on the command line to debug it? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it depends on how you’re processing the params. Normally, CGI doesn’t read params from the command line, I’m surprised your GET example works, unless that script is looking for command line args, which is what I think you’ll need to do in the POST case too.

Comment: @jimtut: It's a specific debugging feature in [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#DEBUGGING).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the module has [a section on debugging](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#DEBUGGING). It says:

> To test the POST method, you may enable full debugging with the -debug pragma. This will allow you to feed newline-delimited name=value pairs to the script on standard input.

So you load the module like this:

```
use CGI '-debug';
```

And you can send data to the POST processer from STDIN. The easiest option might be to create a file:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

And then call the program from the command line, passing your data file as STDIN.

```
./your_cgi.pl < your_data_file.txt
```